# Dynamically assigning variables to pandas functions

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, variables

I want to dynamically assign the pandas data frame variables to `dataframe, Up_dataframe, Down_dataframe` the dataframe variables would be named as the following `df_dataframe, UP_dataframe, Down_dataframe`.

How would I be able to fix the code below and assign the variables?

```py
import pandas as pd


def run():

    dataframe = {
        "Values": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "Montly PnL": [10, 2, 2, 1],
        "Long Montly PnL": [232, 12, 3, 4],
        "Short Montly PnL": [21, 2, 1, 5],
    }
    Up_dataframe = {
        "Values": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "Montly PnL": [55, 6, 5, 5],
        "Long Montly PnL": [1, 4, 22, 4],
        "Short Montly PnL": [5, 2, 1, 4],
    }
    Down_dataframe = {
        "Values": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "Montly PnL": [4, 2, 23, 12],
        "Long Montly PnL": [221, 45, 2, 1],
        "Short Montly PnL": [1, 6, 2, 44],
    }

    for k, v in zip(
        {"df_dataframe": None, "UP_dataframe": None, "Down_dataframe": None}.keys(),
        [dataframe, Up_dataframe, Down_dataframe],
    ):
        exec(f"{k} = {pd.DataFrame(data=v).set_index('Values')}")


run()
```

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: *dynamically named variable* -> No. Just use a dictionary with the desired keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign dynamically by using [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) instead of `exec` at the end of your function, like this:

```
def run():
    ...
    for k, v in zip(
        {"df_dataframe": None, "UP_dataframe": None, "Down_dataframe": None}.keys(),
        [dataframe, Up_dataframe, Down_dataframe],
    ):
        globals()[k] = pd.DataFrame(data=v).set_index("Values")

run()
print(df_dataframe)
```

This code will output the following, even though `df_dataframe` is not statically assigned in your code:

```
        Montly PnL  Long Montly PnL  Short Montly PnL
Values
1               10              232                21
2                2               12                 2
3                2                3                 1
4                1                4                 5
```